# Apply specific color to !important in CSS using listings

Tags: color, listings, code, css

**Problem:**

I wish to apply a gray color to `!important` in CSS when using listings. I have managed to modify so that the color is different after `:` but how can I modify the code below so only `!important` gets targeted?

**Specific code:**

```
% Targets the colon in CSS code
\makeatletter
\def\colorcolonother#1#2{%
  \expandafter\ifx\the\lst@token:%
    \color{#1}%
  \else
    \color{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother
```

**Minimal Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,cmyk]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

% --------------------------------------------------------------
% Color definitions
% --------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{editorGray}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0.2}
\definecolor{editorBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.35, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorPink}{cmyk}{0, 1, 0, 0}
\definecolor{editorDarkOrange}{cmyk}{0, 0.8, 0.9, 0}
\definecolor{editorPurple}{cmyk}{0.75, 1, 0, 0}

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Targets the colon in CSS code
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\makeatletter
\def\colorcolonother#1#2{%
  \expandafter\ifx\the\lst@token:%
    \color{#1}%
  \else
    \color{#2}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
% Changes symbol colors for { and } in CSS
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\CodeSymbol}[1]{\textcolor{black}{#1}}

\lstdefinestyle{css}
{
  stringstyle=\colorcolonother{editorBlue}{editorPurple},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray},
  keywordstyle=\color{editorBlue},
  identifierstyle=\color{editorDarkOrange},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray},
  %
  sensitive=true,
  % Line numbers
  xleftmargin={14pt},
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,
  firstnumber=1,
  numberfirstline=true,
  numberstyle=\color{black},
  frame=l,
  % Keywords
  keywords={%
% CSS properties
  accelerator,azimuth,background,background-attachment,
  background-color,background-image,background-position,
  background-position-x,background-position-y,background-repeat,
  behavior,border,border-bottom,border-bottom-color,
  border-bottom-style,border-bottom-width,border-collapse,
  border-color,border-left,border-left-color,border-left-style,
  border-left-width,border-right,border-right-color,
  border-right-style,border-right-width,border-spacing,
  border-style,border-top,border-top-color,border-top-style,
  border-top-width,border-width,bottom,caption-side,clear,
  clip,color,content,counter-increment,counter-reset,cue,
  cue-after,cue-before,cursor,direction,display,elevation,
  empty-cells,filter,float,font,font-family,font-size,
  font-size-adjust,font-stretch,font-style,font-variant,
  font-weight,height,ime-mode,include-source,
  layer-background-color,layer-background-image,layout-flow,
  layout-grid,layout-grid-char,layout-grid-char-spacing,
  layout-grid-line,layout-grid-mode,layout-grid-type,left,
  letter-spacing,line-break,line-height,list-style,
  list-style-image,list-style-position,list-style-type,margin,
  margin-bottom,margin-left,margin-right,margin-top,
  marker-offset,marks,max-height,max-width,min-height,
  min-width,transition-duration,transition-property,
  transition-timing-function,transform,
  -moz-transform,-moz-binding,-moz-border-radius,
  -moz-border-radius-topleft,-moz-border-radius-topright,
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright,-moz-border-radius-bottomleft,
  -moz-border-top-colors,-moz-border-right-colors,
  -moz-border-bottom-colors,-moz-border-left-colors,-moz-opacity,
  -moz-outline,-moz-outline-color,-moz-outline-style,
  -moz-outline-width,-moz-user-focus,-moz-user-input,
  -moz-user-modify,-moz-user-select,orphans,outline,
  outline-color,outline-style,outline-width,overflow,
  overflow-X,overflow-Y,padding,padding-bottom,padding-left,
  padding-right,padding-top,page,page-break-after,
  page-break-before,page-break-inside,pause,pause-after,
  pause-before,pitch,pitch-range,play-during,position,quotes,
  -replace,richness,right,ruby-align,ruby-overhang,
  ruby-position,-set-link-source,size,speak,speak-header,
  speak-numeral,speak-punctuation,speech-rate,stress,
  scrollbar-arrow-color,scrollbar-base-color,
  scrollbar-dark-shadow-color,scrollbar-face-color,
  scrollbar-highlight-color,scrollbar-shadow-color,
  scrollbar-3d-light-color,scrollbar-track-color,table-layout,
  text-align,text-align-last,text-decoration,text-indent,
  text-justify,text-overflow,text-shadow,text-transform,
  text-autospace,text-kashida-space,text-underline-position,top,
  unicode-bidi,-use-link-source,vertical-align,visibility,
  voice-family,volume,white-space,widows,width,word-break,
  word-spacing,word-wrap,writing-mode,z-index,zoom
  },%
  morecomment=[l][\color{darkgray}]{//},
  morecomment=[s][\color{darkgray}]{/*}{*/},
  alsoletter={.\#},
  morestring=[s]{:}{;},
  alsodigit={-;:},
  literate=*{\{}{{\CodeSymbol{\{}}}1
            {\}}{{\CodeSymbol{\}}}}1
}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  HTML
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\lstdefinestyle{html}
{
  language=html,
  sensitive=true,
  stringstyle=\color{editorPurple},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray},
  keywordstyle=\color{editorPink},
  ndkeywordstyle=\color{editorBlue},
  identifierstyle=\color{editorDarkOrange},
  commentstyle=\color{editorGray},
  tagstyle=\color{editorBlue},
  %
  markfirstintag=true,
  morecomment=[s][\color{darkgray}]{<!-}{-->},
  alsoletter={!-'},
  alsodigit={.:},
  keywords={},
  % Line numbers
  xleftmargin={14pt},
  numbers=left,
  stepnumber=1,
  firstnumber=1,
  numberfirstline=true,
  numberstyle=\color{black},
  % Frame
  frame=l,
  % German umlauts
  literate=
  {á}{{\'a}}1 {é}{{\'e}}1 {í}{{\'i}}1 {ó}{{\'o}}1 {ú}{{\'u}}1
  {Á}{{\'A}}1 {É}{{\'E}}1 {Í}{{\'I}}1 {Ó}{{\'O}}1 {Ú}{{\'U}}1
  {à}{{\`a}}1 {è}{{\`e}}1 {ì}{{\`i}}1 {ò}{{\`o}}1 {ù}{{\`u}}1
  {À}{{\`A}}1 {È}{{\'E}}1 {Ì}{{\`I}}1 {Ò}{{\`O}}1 {Ù}{{\`U}}1
  {ä}{{\"a}}1 {ë}{{\"e}}1 {ï}{{\"i}}1 {ö}{{\"o}}1 {ü}{{\"u}}1
  {Ä}{{\"A}}1 {Ë}{{\"E}}1 {Ï}{{\"I}}1 {Ö}{{\"O}}1 {Ü}{{\"U}}1
  {â}{{\^a}}1 {ê}{{\^e}}1 {î}{{\^i}}1 {ô}{{\^o}}1 {û}{{\^u}}1
  {Â}{{\^A}}1 {Ê}{{\^E}}1 {Î}{{\^I}}1 {Ô}{{\^O}}1 {Û}{{\^U}}1
  {œ}{{\oe}}1 {Œ}{{\OE}}1 {æ}{{\ae}}1 {Æ}{{\AE}}1 {ß}{{\ss}}1
  {ç}{{\c c}}1 {Ç}{{\c C}}1 {ø}{{\o}}1 {å}{{\r a}}1 {Å}{{\r A}}1
  {€}{{\EUR}}1 {£}{{\pounds}}1 {\\-}{}{0\discretionary{-}{}{}}
}
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Language and inline definitions for listings
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\lstdefinelanguage{HTML5}{style=html}
\lstdefinelanguage{CSS3}{style=css}
\lstMakeShortInline[language=CSS3]^
\lstMakeShortInline[language=HTML5]|
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
%  Code style
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------
\lstset{%
  % General design
  inputencoding=utf8,
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},
  basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily\upshape\lst@ifdisplaystyle\tiny\fi,
  frame=none,
  escapeinside=$$,
  % Languages
  language=HTML5,
  alsolanguage=CSS3,
  % Code
  tabsize=2,
  showtabs=false,
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  extendedchars=true,
  breaklines=false
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=CSS3,numbers=left,firstnumber=1]
.blue-header {
    color: blue !important;
}
.red-header {
    color: red;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Desired output:**

The keyword `!important` should be modified with the color `editorGray`.